# \1 better written as $1 warning, but $1 does not work

Tags: rename

I want to rename files that include like "text name [1].m4a" to "text name [01].m4a".

At first, I wrote:

```
rename -n "s/\[(\d)\]/\[0$1\]/" *.m4a
```

This command showed `[0]` instead `[01]`.
If I replace `$1` to `\1`, it worked as expected.

```
rename -n "s/\[(\d)\]/\[0\1\]/" *.m4a
```

But there is warning `\1 better written as $1 at (eval 5) line 1.`
Why the first command doesn't work, and how can I rewrite it?

I'm using `File::Rename version 0.20` with `Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS`.

Comment: use single quote in `rename -n 's/\[(\d)\]/\[0$1\]/' *.m4a`

Comment: And you don't need to escape `[` and `]` in the replacement string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `"...$1..."`, with double quotation marks, the shell replaces `$1` by the value of *its* (the shell's) variable, which is empty, before passing the string to `rename`. So `rename` only sees `[0]` and performs the replacement accordingly.

To make the shell pass `$1` literally to `rename`, use single quotes instead of double ones (and as Freddy mentioned, you don't need to escape the brackets in the replacement string either).